# 'DefaultColorbarFontSize' not working

Tags: matlab

I am trying to make this option work in a code like:

```
AxLabMultip = 1.9;
AxFontSiz = 14;

set(groot, ...
   'DefaultColorbarFontSize', 10000, ...              % !?!?!?!?!?!?!?!?!?!?!?!?
   'DefaultAxesFontsize', AxFontSiz, ...              % Affects numbers and labels of axes and colorbar.
   'DefaultAxesLabelFontSizeMultiplier', AxLabMultip) % Affects labels of axes (not colorbar).

xyz=ones(10);
imagesc(xyz)
    xlabel('x')
    ylabel('y')
    trash = colorbar;
        xlabel(trash,'z')
```

But the `'DefaultColorbarFontSize'` value makes no difference. Then I guess **why**, and if there is **any other solution** than adding an awful `'fontsize', AxFontSiz*AxLabMultip` option to the last `xlabel`, every time I have a `imagesc`... Also, the `colorbar` tick labels seem to be still **a bit smaller** than the axes ones, so I have to add `set(trash,'Fontsize', AxFontSiz)` to every plot...

I am using Matlab R2015a.

Comment: The default behaviour for the `FontSize` of the colorbar is that it is derived from the axes'  `FontSize`. If you do not set any font size and do for instance `set(gca, 'FontSize',18)`, you will see that this changes the colorbar's font size. Perhaps this behaviour overrules the `DefaultColorBarFontSize` setting. From the Mathworks website: " If you change the axes font size, then MATLAB automatically sets the colorbar font size to 90% of the axes font size. If you manually set the colorbar font size, then changing the axes font size does not affect the colorbar."

Comment: I played around a bit and noticed that also other colorbar properties related to fonts do not work. I think they are being overruled by axes properties, as these do work and also change the colorbar properties related to fonts. I don't think you'll be able to do it in a really nice way. If you are keeping all the figures open and don't want to add a line everytime, you could do this: `h =  findobj('type','figure'); %find all figures` then `trash = findobj(get(h(i),'Children'),'Tag','Colorbar');`  `trash.FontSize=20;` and embed the whole thing into a for loop to iterate over all figures.